# How can I use processing.app.Preferences in java?

Tags: java, serial-port

I wrote a java program to reading data from serial port.
But I have an error.
Can you help me?

```
import gnu.io.CommPortIdentifier;
import gnu.io.SerialPort;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import processing.app.Preferences;

public class Main {
    static InputStream input;
    static OutputStream output;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        Preferences.init(null);
        System.out.println("Using port: " + Preferences.get("serial.port"));
        CommPortIdentifier portId = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifier(
                Preferences.get("serial.port"));

        SerialPort port = (SerialPort)portId.open("serial talk", 4000);
        input = port.getInputStream();
        output = port.getOutputStream();
        port.setSerialPortParams(Preferences.getInteger("serial.debug_rate"),
                SerialPort.DATABITS_8,
                SerialPort.STOPBITS_1,
                SerialPort.PARITY_NONE);
        while(true){
            while(input.available()>0) {
                System.out.print((char)(input.read()));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Error: init(String[]) has protected access in Preferences

Comment: Please add a stacktrace to your questions.

Comment: This error is compiler error...

Comment: But if you run it,saw "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - init(java.lang.String[]) has protected access in processing.app.Preferences
 at pkg.Main.main(Main.java:25)
Java Result: 1"

Comment: Do you really have to call Preferences.init(null)? Try to delete this line. It is possible to change class processing.app.Preferences otherwise?